# WordPress : can't find wp-load.php file

Tags: wordpress

This is probably a simple problem, but can't figure it out...

1) I installed the wordpress file directly under the xxxx directory; wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes are all within wordpress file.

2) wp-load.php exists wordpress folder, I copied it into the wp-admin folder as well.

3) wp-config.php exists in wordpress folder.

the errors are as follows:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require_once(../wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-content\plugins\workflow\ajax.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../wp-load.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-content\plugins\workflow\ajax.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

This problem is in plugin folder.

and i add this code in php file :-

```
include("../../../wp-load.php");
if($_POST["do"] == "add_edda_form")
{
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->workflow_content = $wpdb->prefix.'workflow_content';
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["captcha"]) && $_POST["captcha"] != "" && $_SESSION["code"] == $_POST["captcha"] && $_POST["stutjawgmodano"] )
{
$ebdaa_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $wpdb->workflow_content SET
stutjawgmodano = '".$_POST["stutjawgmodano"]."',
stutjawgmodaprice = '".$_POST["stutjawgmodaprice"]."',
stumotazerno = '".$_POST["stumotazerno"]."',
stumotazerprice = '".$_POST["stumotazerprice"]."',
stuenzarno = '".$_POST["stuenzarno"]."',
stuenzarprice = '".$_POST["stuenzarprice"]."',
stuotherno = '".$_POST["stuotherno"]."',
stuotherprice = '".$_POST["stuotherprice"]."',
stutotalno = '".$_POST["stutotalno"]."',
stutotalprice = '".$_POST["stutotalprice"]."',
buldrentno = '".$_POST["buldrentno"]."',
buldrentprice = '".$_POST["buldrentprice"]."',
earthrentno = '".$_POST["earthrentno"]."',
earthrentprice = '".$_POST["earthrentprice"]."',
unrentno = '".$_POST["unrentno"]."',
unrentprice = '".$_POST["unrentprice"]."',
unotherno = '".$_POST["unotherno"]."',
unotherprice = '".$_POST["unotherprice"]."',
untotalno = '".$_POST["untotalno"]."',
untotalprice = '".$_POST["untotalprice"]."',
totalallprice = '".$_POST["totalallprice"]."',
masoolname = '".$_POST["masoolname"]."',
masoolemail = '".$_POST["masoolemail"]."',
masoolid = '".$_POST["masoolid"]."',
unverstyname = '".$_POST["unverstyname"]."',
date = '".time()."'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: Can you please further explain your problem? what are you trying to do and how? the above code should solve your problem including wp-load.php. The error you are encountering now may be caused by some other thing.

Comment: i need to create new plugin and this plugin is to add new row to database, so i need to connect into database to add this row

Comment: Can you please post the code or lines of code that connects or select the database?

Comment: why are you including wp-load.php in your plugin? do you want to access it outside wordpress?

Comment: you can use $wpdb->insert

Comment: when use `$wpdb->insert` its show me `Trying to get property of non-object in `

Answer (score 0):

If the problem exists in the plugins folder. I would remove all plugins and add each one via FTP until you find your culprit.

Once the culprit is found, make sure that application is up to date. If it is and the problem persists, I would suggest contacting the plugin creator and informing them of this error.

Comment: i dont have any plugin, only my plugin